# Capital Gains Tax and Main Residence

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax, primary-residence

If I changed my main residence 4 years ago, but did not inform HMRC, then can i register for the dates i actually changed my main residence when i sell my older property, in order to avoid paying more capital gains tax than I "ought to" ?

I have found [this link](https://www.gov.uk/tax-sell-home/nominating-a-home), but not sure what to make of it.

Comment: That link is pretty clear - you should tell HMRC in writing when you change your main residence, and it must be within 2 years. If you tell them how they will probably let you backdate the change by 2 years but not by the 4 that you want to. What is it that is making you say you “don’t know what to make of it”?

Comment: Well, it goes on to say... "If you do not nominate a home and you sell one of your properties you must work out how long you lived in it as your main home," which is unclear to me. Not sure what the relevance of the 2 years is given that.